# Center screen vertically against an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I center the browser viewport on an element position?

I can find several examples on achieving the opposite but nothing on centering the screen on an element.

**EDIT:** I am talking about vertically centering the screen against an element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example that will vertically center the window on the div you click on: http://jsfiddle.net/BcY7B/

I'm not sure if this totally solves what you're looking for. Please be aware that there isn't any way to center the window on a div that is too high up or far down to be centered vertically (because the page ends, so it can't scroll further to center it). You could get around this by modifying the height of the page the necessary amount, but I highly doubt that will give you the effect you're looking for.